# google map infobox position

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3, position

I've been googling that question for some time and all I got is headache. I add google marker with infobox on my google map, but the infobox is located lower than marker, how ever I would really appreciate it to be over the marker. Does anyone know how to do it?

And please don't gove some links to somewhere, I was seeing it for a loooong time today. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

set the `alignBottom`-property of the infoBox to `true` (default is `false`). For further adjustments of the position use the `pixelOffset`-property of the infoBox

Comment: What I have right now is already working as expected, the infobox is already on the top of the marker. I have also a div on the uppermost part of the map, and on some occasions, the infobox is overlapper by it. How would I adjust the infobox such that when the infobox is being overlapped by the div, it will adjust it's position, making it lower than the usual position? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

By default the infoBox will point the bottom left of the marker. You can simply do this:

```
var ib= new InfoBox({
    ....//other properties,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0) //where your marker's height is 25px
});
```

Comment: I think the first number is the `x-offset` (width) and the second is the `y-ofset` (height).  At least that's what I was seeing when I added this to my InfoBox settings

Answer (score 3):

```
infobox = new InfoBox({
         content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
         disableAutoPan: false,
         maxWidth: 150,
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -45),
         zIndex: null,
         boxStyle: {
            background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') 0% 100% no-repeat",
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: "280px"
        },
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        alignBottom: true
    });


#infobox {
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-shadow:0 -1px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0  8px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
```

// Load the customized arrow from local