# Creating a InfoBox window above a marker with the stub in the correct place

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I've been working from the InfoBox documentation and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938939/google-map-infobox-position) to try to get an InfoBox looking almost the same as a standard InfoWindow as a starting point for some slight cosmetic changes.

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twrv9jvj/1/) the 'stub' that connects the InfoBox to the marker is still positioned at the top of the InfoBox.

I've tried to use `backgroundPosition` (commented out when you first open the fiddle) as follows in the `boxStyle` parameter, but it doesn't work.

```
     boxStyle: {
        backgroundImage: "url('https://directory.fsf.org/w/extensions/SemanticDrilldown/skins/down-arrow.png')",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        /*backgroundPosition: "center bottom",*/
        opacity: 0.75,
        width: "280px"
    },
```

How can I move the stub down to the bottom center rather than the top left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it with an `:after` selector to the infobox. Like this

```
#infobox:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 125px;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
```

See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/twrv9jvj/3/)

p.s. I didn't remove the old one from your JS. That's why you'll see it in the screen still.

Supporting documentation per OP's request

There is plenty of documentation of CSS selector specifically the `:before` and `:after`selectors. Some of it, and probably the most basic information will be found in [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp).

[**SmashingMagazine**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) also has a lot more detialed information and usefulness of this concept.

By hacking the element with a selector you can also style according to behaviors. such as `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`, `:inactive`, `:empty`, and `:blank`

The actual triangle is built by drawing a small rectangle using borders and clipping one side of the borders. See [**this link**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) in CSS tricks on how to build a CSS triangle.

As far as choosing `:before` or `:after`, there isn't a definite explanation as to which one you should use. Depending which one you use you will have to reposition accordingly. In some specific situations such as adding a font awesome icon via CSS selectors, it would make sense to add it to the `:before` selector if it is going to precede the element it is being attached to or use the `:after` selector if it's going to proceed the element instead

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing it. I also tried using `:before` and managed to put a 'title' box on the infoBox as well. Can you explain a bit about how this works, for example how the shape of the stub is defined, is the `:before` and `:after` option documented anywhere?

Comment: I took the opportunity to ask that question separately for you. go check it out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827794/when-to-use-before-or-after

Comment: thanks for that. Looks like that's got a really interesting discussion started. I did wonder to start with whether there was something in the InfoBox code that was tweaking things based on the css, but it's really useful to know that these css hacks can be used anywhere and the discussion in your new post really add to the understanding of how and why that works. I'll have to have a play with the css border hack as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background position on `.infoBox` and change the `margin-top` to `margin-bottom` on `#infobox`.

```
.infoBox {
    background-position: center bottom;
}

#infobox {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twrv9jvj/2/)

Comment: That seems a nice and simple way of doing it.